# On AWS elastic search {"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-elasticsearch

I have created AWS elasticsearch domain

https://search-xx-xx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/

On click both elastic url and kibana below is the error i got

{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}

[image]

Below is code which is working fine

```
import boto3
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
                   credentials.secret_key,
                   session.region_name, 'es',
                   session_token=credentials.token)
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['https://search-testelastic-2276kyz2u4l3basec63onfq73a.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'],
    http_auth=awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    es.cluster.health()
    es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400)
    r = [{'Name': 'Dr. Christopher DeSimone', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir (Aamir)', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard M. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Eliana M. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Joseph J. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Michael R. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Darryl H. Aarons', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. William B. Aarons', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Sirike T. Aasmaa', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Jacobo A. Abadi', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}]
    for e in enumerate(r):
         es.index(index="my-index", body=e[1])
```

Below is the access policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:xxxxxx:domain/xxxxx/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This error would indicate your ElasticSearch service does not support anonymous requests (those not signed with valid IAM credentials).

Although your policy sees ok the official allow all policy looks like the below

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:xxxxxx:domain/xxxxx/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: probably need to set the [session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html) variables as an alternative

Comment: Thanks its working fine, where you got this Sir, in documentation i could not see

Comment: My kibana is taking too much time to load

Comment: Its from the console when you have the ability to generate, it has a predetermined option named "Allow open access to the domain"

Comment: Do you also have a security group attached to the domain? It will need to allow inbound access :)

Comment: No Chris, its dev-testing elastic searvice with t2 small, so no security policy

Comment: So to confirm its not in a VPC?

Comment: Hmm does accessing it in any kind of incognito window help?

Comment: still its loading only since 5 munutes and after that pop will come saying kibana not loaded properly `https://search-xx-xx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/app/kibana ` after 5 minutes its visibel now :) is there any way to make it faster

Comment: So Kibanas UI loads but it gives you that message? That sounds as if Kibana cannot talk to ElasticSearch :(

Comment: @ChrisWilliams if I use this policy, I get the following problem: 

UpdateElasticsearchDomainConfig: {"message":"Apply a restrictive access policy to your domain"} 

Do you have a hint for me? Thanks

Comment: It’s indicating that the policy is too open @Schaumkuesschen. Is your ES a VPC based or Over internet based deployment?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams its over internet based deployment.

Comment: As its over the internet the above policy would allow anyone to access it, if you take a look at the IP condition you can lock it down to an appropriate set of IPs. An example can be found in this link link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html#es-ac-types-ip

Comment: Adding this policy resolved the error for me while using fine-grained access on a single OpenSearch instance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use AWS Signature authentication method at the Postman, for tests.

In postman, go to `Authorization` tab and under `Type`, select `AWS Signature`, get your AWS Access Key and Secret Key from `Security Credentials` > `Create Access Key`.

Add your region in postman and service name as `es` and then hit `Send`. It should work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).