# how to delete values in elastic search after being deleted on dynamo? ( appsync and amplify )

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

hope everyone is having a great day, I have an issue when it comes to deleting values through elastic search usually I would delete the values through app sync which removes it however we faced an issue where someone deleted it through dynamo and it still exists in elastic is there a way to delete the values from elastic search

thank you for your time

Comment: Currently how you are syncing data from DynamoDB to Elastic search? Also mention how you are deleting data from elastic search?

Comment: @LibuMathew we use appsync graphql if you delete it through graphql it deletes it from both dynamo and elastic im trying to access kibana but it keeps giving me 
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62738960/on-aws-elastic-search-messageuser-anonymous-is-not-authorized-to-perform

Comment: i tried the solution presented and i got UpdateElasticsearchDomainConfig: {"message":"Apply a restrictive access policy to your domain"} when changing the policy in es